# how to set 2i with riak local client

Tags: erlang, riak

does anyone know how i set 2i to object that created with riak_object

```
OBJ = riak_object:new()
```

i want to work with riak local client and i trying to do something similar to this:

```
Obj1 = riakc_obj:new(Bucket, UniqKey, Tablet),
MD1  = riakc_obj:get_update_metadata(Obj1),
MD2  = riakc_obj:set_secondary_index(MD1, {{integer_index, IdxTS}, [FirstTS, LastTS]}),
Obj2 = riakc_obj:update_metadata(Obj1, MD2)
```

but i can't found something similar in riak_object module, i only found examples on how to query 2i not how to set it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    {ok, C} = riak:local_client(),
    O = riak_object:new(<<"bucket">>, <<"key">>, <<"hello">>),

    O2 = riak_object:update_metadata(
        O,
        dict:from_list([{<<"index">>, [{<<"my_index_bin">>, <<"index_key">>}]}])
    ),
    C:put(O2).
```

Comment: still getting errors,
also how you can store integer index?
i try this:
```
    Obj2 = riak_object:update_metadata(
            Obj1,
            dict:from_list([{<<"index">>,
            [{list_to_binary(lists:append(IdxTS, "_int")),
    [FirstTS, LastTS]}]}])
    ),
```
and it don't like it when i do:
```
    C:put(Obj2).
```

Comment: Just checked, everything works perfectly fine:
{ok, [<<"key">>]} = C:get_index(<<"bucket">>, {eq, <<"my_index_bin">>, <<"index_key">>}).
(note I edit original example and cut one ")" to fix syntax error)

Comment: it works :), thanks, also you know how i can insert more values to the index?
somthing like:
dict:from_list([{<<"index">>, [{<<"my_index_bin">>, [<<"index_key1">>, <<"index_key2">>, <<"index_key3">>...]}]}])